# While I'm running Maui android application showing Error Failed processing manifest and resource xml/network_security_config not found

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, maui

step 1: create a one webapi through connect the maui application

step 2:my baseaddress is http://localhost:5026/ but I am change this http://10.0.2.2:5026/

step 3: now I am adding new XML file (network_security_config):

[image]

step 4:this my Androidmanifest.xml

[image]

step 5: Step 5: You're encountering two errors:

> Error APT2260: This error indicates that the resource network_security_config.xml is not found. Ensure that the file is located in the correct directory, typically Resources/xml/network_security_config.xml.
>
> Error APT2067: This error suggests a failure in processing the manifest, possibly due to the missing resource. Once you resolve the resource not found error, this issue should be resolved as well.

I need a solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the build action of network_security_config.xml is **AndroidResource**.

- Right-click on the network_security_config.xml file in the Solution Explorer.
- Select Properties from the context menu.
- In the Properties window, find the Build Action property.
- Set the Build Action to AndroidResource from the dropdown menu.